# Custom calendar cell in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to make a custom cell for `PyQt.QtGui.QCalendarWidget`. I need to add a short small text to the bottom of some calendar cells, is it possible? If so, could anyone point me in the right direction?

So far the idea is to subclass the `QCalendarWidget` and override its `paintCell` method. However I have no idea what to do there. I've tried to look at the Qt and the code of the widget, but it's pretty complex and I didn't find the place where they actualy paint the cell. So I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reimplement painting. Just call the default implementation and add text drawing:

```
class MyCalendar(QtGui.QCalendarWidget):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QtGui.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self,parent)

  def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
    QtGui.QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
    if date.day() % 5 == 0: # example condition based on date
      painter.drawText(rect.bottomLeft(), "test")
```

You need to set proper height for the widget to ensure that there is enough space in cells to display the text.

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved me so much time figuring this out.